# probability of infinite union of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(U_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ be iid with $U_1\sim U[0,1]$.

Calculate $P(\,\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \{U_i\in [0,x]\}\,)$ where $x\in (0,1]$.

I tried to apply

$$P(\,\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \{U_i\in [0,x]\}\,)=1-P(\,\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \{U_i\notin [0,x]\}\,)=1-\prod_{i=1}^\infty P(U_i\notin [0,x])=1-\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1-x)=1$$

Right?

Comment: Why don't you think it makes sense?

Comment: ok if i think about it intuitively it must be true. Can anyone agree with that?

Comment: I agree with you that it must be true. And your calculation looks convincing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear how you can justify $P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (U_i\notin[0,x])\right) = \prod_{i=1}^\infty P(U_i\notin[0,x])$ because independence of an infinite collection of events is usually defined as independence of any finite subcollection.

Instead you could write $P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (U_i\notin[0,x])\right)\leq P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n (U_i\notin[0,x])\right) = \prod_{i=1}^nP(U_i\notin[0,x])=(1-x)^n$. Letting $n\to \infty$ yields $P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty (U_i\notin[0,x])\right) = 0$, as wanted.